# Is there a general formula the solutions of a polynomial equation of the form $Ax^n + Bx^{n-1} + C = 0$?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Is there a general formula for the solutions of a polynomial equation of the form $$Ax^n + Bx^{n-1} + C = 0,$$ where $A$, $B$, $C$, and $n$ are constants?

Comment: A general formula for the solutions of that polynomial? Is $N$ a real number or is it a natural number greater than $1$?

Comment: Structurally, the equation you have is very similar to the one appear in [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical). At least when $N$ is a positive integer, you may be able to express $X$ as some sort of generalized hypergeometric function in $A,B,C$.

Comment: Yes, sorry N is positive integer

Answer (score 3):

The Galois group of the splitting field of, for example, $x^5 - x^4 + 1$, is isomorphic to $S_5$, which is not solvable, and hence the roots of that polynomial are not solvable in radicals. Hence, there is no general formula for the roots of a real polynomial of the form $A x^n + B x^{n - 1} + C$ in terms of radicals. (See the [Wikipedia article on the Abel-Ruffini Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) for more.)

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it useful.